# Add blockquote image dynamically using SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic3

Could you tell me how to dynamically add `blockquote` image using `SCSS`?

*Note:*

I have `svg` image on this path: `assets/icon/left-quote.svg`

This is what I need.

[image]

Here you can see where it comes from the backend(i.e. `blockquote` tags).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-selector as follows:

```css
blockquote {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkblue;
}

blockquote::before {
  display: block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  content: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Quote_left_font_awesome.svg");
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  Parties prenantes de cette organisation (marchande ou non-marchande) par rapport aux attentes et besoins
</blockquote>
```

To make it more SCSS-like:

```
blockquote {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkblue;

  &::before {
    display: block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    content: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Quote_left_font_awesome.svg");
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working when I used url. But this is not working. Do you know why? `content: url('./assets/icon/left-quote.svg');`

Comment: Could you tell me how to load it using project's file as this `'./assets/icon/left-quote.svg'`?

Comment: I don't know how your project gets built, what gets packaged where, what location you're referencing from. If all else fails, base64 encode the SVG and use a data URI.

Comment: It is in the `www` folder after the build. I normally use above kind of URL for all the `images`,`SVGs` and etc. `www\assets\icon\left-quote.svg`. Any clue?

Comment: This is how it looks when I applied your solution. Could you see any issue there? https://i.imgur.com/ezkhgQl.png

Comment: Can you load the image directly in your browser? I'm thinking that whatever build process you have is not correctly rewriting the URLs in the SCSS files. There have been issues with the Sass loader before, e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5213

Comment: Could you tell me how you generated your url? i.e. svg file ?
 `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Quote_left_font_awesome.svg`

Comment: I didn't generate anything. Just googled for left quote SVG and used one that I found on a domain that is not likely to change anytime soon, i.e. wikimedia.org

Comment: The one you linked from the S3 bucket has hard-coded width/height attributes, both set to 512px, that's why it shows up that big. The one I use uses a relative setting of 100% for the width and height, that's why it scales according to what I set in the CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Great explanation and the support. I have used `png` and now it works with your code. Cheers :)